# What criteria should be considered when comparing 2 robot simulation/modelling software?

Tags: simulation, simulator

I want to compare MapleSim (Maplesoft) to SimMechanics (Mathworks) what should my criteria of comparison be?

Comment: Although this is a *list* question, it does seem reasonably well constrained and the first answer looks like it might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most important criteria are

- the purpose of your simulator (do you need contact physics? how complex are your models? )
- your fluency in both solutions
- the size and quality of the documentation/community
- is the code you are going to write for the simulator re-usable for real system ?
- what is the licencing policy of the simulator (and its price)

In general there is no magic simulator, each comes with its drawbacks and plus. So the choice of a simulator is a compromise between your needs and the solutions available on the market.